# Turn data in to time series using ts in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data set with 2 colomns ,the first one is representing a week(goes from 21-39) and the second one is numbers representing some result in a medical test.

this is how the data looks

```
head(s)
Week  ILI
21    11
22    14
23    34
24    56
25    56
21    67
22    4
23    45
```

I would like to have the data looking like this so I can plot it

```
21  22  23  24  25 

11  14  34  56  56
67  4   45  72  23
```

I use `ts(s$ILI,start = 21,end = 25,frequency = 5)`
and get one big vector of all the values.

Comment: Take a look at this quick reference for `zoo` and see if you can't solve your problem then: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The question did not describe the plot desired so we will assume here that we want to plot the two sets of weeks separately.  Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we add a `group` column to distinguish the sets of weeks, split that to create a 2 column zoo object and then optionally convert that to ts class.

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, group = ave(Week, Week, FUN = seq_along))

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF2, index = "Week", split = "group")
tt <- as.ts(z)
```

Now we can plot either the `"zoo"` object `z` or the `"ts"` object `tt`.

```
plot(z)
plot(tt)
```

**Note:**  Input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Week  ILI
21    11
22    14
23    34
24    56
25    56
21    67
22    4
23    45
24    72
25    23"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```